# Is there a way to an implicit equation into parametric form?

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

For example, take the implicit equation for the unit circle

$\qquad x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Is there a function `Parameterize[x^2 + y^2 == 1]` that would return a vector valued function

$\qquad v(t) = \{\cos(t),\,\sin(t)\}$

I've come across `ParametricNDSolve`, but can't seem to figure out how it works.

I may be asking the wrong question, please let me know if you think that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

This is usually a tough problem to solve symbolically.  The following function doesn't check whether system was solve, nor does it remove singular solutions.

```
ClearAll[parametrize];
(* Polar parametrization centered at basepoint *)
parametrize[eqn_, v : {x_, y_}, t_, basepoint : {_, _}] :=      
  parametrize[eqn, v, t, 
   Function[{param, elim}, basepoint + elim*{Cos[param], Sin[param]}]];
(* Default: polar parametrization centered at origin as in OP *)
parametrize[eqn_, v : {x_, y_}, t_, 
   paramform_ : Function[{param, elim}, elim*{Cos[param], Sin[param]}]
   ] :=
  Module[{r},
   Simplify@Solve[
     Eliminate[Flatten@{eqn, v == paramform[t, r]}, r],
     {x, y}
     ]
   ];
```

Examples:

```
parametrize[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}, t]
```

> ```
> (*  {{x -> -Cos[t], y -> -Sin[t]}, {x -> Cos[t], y -> Sin[t]}}  *)
> ```

```
parametrize[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}, t, {1, 0}]
```

> ```
> (*  {{x -> 1, y -> 0}, {x -> -Cos[2 t], y -> -2 Cos[t] Sin[t]}}  *)
> ```

```
(* The "Pythagorean Triples" parametrization *)
parametrize[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}, m, 
 Function[{m, x}, {x, m*(x + 1)}]]
```

> ```
> (*  {{x -> -1, y -> 0}, {x -> (1 - m^2)/(1 + m^2), y -> (2 m)/(1 + m^2)}}  *)
> ```

Comment: See [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=solve/parametrized)  how Maple does it.

Comment: @user64494 The generic Maple approach is similar to my last example, an algebraic (rational) parameterization of the pencil of lines through a point on the curve. The approach tends to produce a parametrization that misses a point (which is the limit as the parameter approaches infinity).  The form OP desired was different, and I made a parametrization based on a polar angle the default.  I added the optional `paramform` to show the algebraic approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a numerical complement to my other answer.  Just integrate orthogonally to the gradient.  The code below produces a parameterization by arc length.  It should fail (stop integration) if it reaches a singular point.  `NDSolve` does not allow the domain of integration to be infinite on both sides, that is, `{t, -Infinity, Infinity}`.  If you want to start in the middle and integrate both ways, alter `{t, 0, Infinity}` in `nParametrize` accordingly.

```
ClearAll[nParametrize];
ClearAll[periodify];
periodify[list_List] := ReplacePart[list, -1 -> First@list];

ClearAll[closeIF];
closeIF[ifn_InterpolatingFunction] := Interpolation[Transpose@{
     ifn["Grid"],
     periodify@ifn["ValuesOnGrid"], 
     periodify@Derivative[1][ifn]["ValuesOnGrid"]}, 
   PeriodicInterpolation -> True];
nParametrize[eqn_, v : {x_, y_}, basepoint : {x0_, y0_}, 
   tol_ : 0.001] :=
  Module[{vel, t, periodicQ = False},
   vel = Simplify[
     ComplexExpand@Normalize@Cross@D[eqn /. Equal -> Subtract, {v}],
     eqn];
   With[{res = NDSolve[
       {{x'[t], y'[t]} == (vel /. u : x | y :> u[t]),
        x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0,
        WhenEvent[
         x[t] == x0 && 
          Abs[y[t] - y0] < (tol + Sqrt@$MachineEpsilon*Abs[y0]),
         periodicQ = True; "StopIntegration"],
        WhenEvent[
         y[t] == y0 && 
          Abs[x[t] - x0] < (tol + Sqrt@$MachineEpsilon*Abs[x0]),
         periodicQ = True; "StopIntegration"]},
       v, {t, 0, Infinity}]},
    res /. if_InterpolatingFunction /; periodicQ :> closeIF[if]
    ]
   ];
```

Example:

```
psol = nParametrize[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}, {1, 0}]
```

[image]

In this case, `nParametrize` constructs a periodic solution, so in effect the domain is all real numbers (up to machine float limitations).

```
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. psol // Evaluate, {t, 10, 14}]
```

[image]